# Object to authorize method of Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

When we create new FormRequest we have method

```
public function authorize()
{
    return 1;
}
```

My question is, can I have here something from form, any eloquent model object?

Like

`public function authorize(Posts $post)` ?

I realized that I can read request data here by e.g. `$this->content`

But Can I send here whole object?

Let's asumme we have `post` collection in view.

I have form

If I could have something like

`<form method="post" action="{{ route('temat.post.like', $post) }}">`

And in this route's controller method `public function post_like(LikePost $request)`

And then in authorize method called `class LikePost extends FormRequest` have this `$post` like `public function authorize(Posts $post)`

I don't know if it is even possible to get it somehow in authorize method, I looked for this and I don't think is it possible but I may be wrong, that's why I ask

I mean to have in this `authorize()` method Eloquent Model fetched by this parameter, just like Controllers do.

e.g.

`public function authorize(Users $user)`

url: `/like/15`

Fetched User Model by id 15

and in method we can use it.

Like

```
public function authorize(Users $user)
    {
        return $user->status;
    }
```

Where $user is User Eloquent Model

Comment: is authorize a method in controller?
 Maybe that is what you're looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @RafałŁyczkowski no, as I said it is method in Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you want to achieve. 
Request classes should not resolve models since it's not their responsibilities.

- Controllers are created to consume requests and manage all entities and busiess logic execution (entities, repositories access, creating resources using manager classes)
- Request class should only manage all aspects related with specific service request (checking, validating, formatting, accessing)

If you need that, I'd recommend to create a FormRequest singleton with getters, that will recognize your model bindings.

You have to register model bindings to resolve specific model on method - request param must be related with concrete class

```
FormRequest::bind('user_id', function ($value) {
    return User::where('id', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Now you have two options:

- a) If you need loaded entity in method's params => You have to create something like resolver accessing method. You can try doing so in __call() method. Since

> __call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

you have to wrap you bindings like so

```
class FormRequest {
   public funciton authorize(User $user);
}

class FormRequestCaller { 
    private $formRequest;

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $entity = FormRequest::resolve($name, $arguments);
        return $this->$name($entity);
    } 

    public static function resolve($bindingName, $data) {
        return call_user_func_array($bindings[$bindingName], $data);
    }
}
```

- b) another way is to create accesso

-

```
class FormRequest {

   public funciton authorize() {
       $user = $this->getUser(); 
   }

   public function __call($name, $arguments) {
     return FormRequest::resolve(ucfirst(str_replace('get','',$name), $arguments));
   }

   public static function resolve($bindingName, $data) {
        return call_user_func_array($bindings[$bindingName], $data);
   }
}
```

Of course, this should has to be adjusted, but you should get the point.

Comment: Your comment "Request classes should not resolve models since it's not their responsibilities." Laravel request object generates a User model